# Do I need to sanitize the code if am using eval()

Tags: php, eval, sanitization

I am storing forms as well as the form processing scripts, javascript validation scripts and form CSS in the database, am using `eval()` for PHP code, so my question is do I need to to `htmlspecialchars()`, `htmlentities()`?

Anyways am using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `nl2br()` and ya don't warn me about how to use `eval()` securely or `eval` is `evil` etc etc, that's not the concern here, the thing is if am not using `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` the html will go as it has being posted in the database like `<` will be `<` and not `&lt;` so do I need to use those functions or they are not really required in this case?

Comment: If you don't use one of them there's big XSS hole. Well, actually there already is a security hole with the name of `eval`.

Comment: @PLB only the system administrator will be accessing the code so no issue of XSS, read my question, I said don't warn me about the security, user inputs wont be executed, only the system administrators will be doing so

Comment: You obviously do not care about writing robust code, so why do you not try them all out and see what works? If it does not work then you will get an error. Keep trying until it works, and you will have your answer.

Comment: I'd warn even if you warned me that you'd shoot if I warned you. ;) But that's not the case. `eval` starts new php process that's also not desirable. And I am unclear now with your needs. If you want to render as html code in browser, you definitely need to use either `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities`. If you want to render web-page with proper mark-up from db, you don't need.

Comment: eval is evil despite of what you think about the matter

Comment: You guys really go with standards all the time,s standard says its bad than it's bad, it says good than wow, run behind it, but I don't go that way, that function has real power and am using it anyways thanks everyone

Comment: The function has more power to unintentionally do evil than intentionally do good. You haven't revealed why the admin should enter code that is eval'd - if you did, a better solution for the same might have come up.

Comment: @Sven I am generalisingg a system for different workgroups having different forms, no better option than `eval()`

Comment: If the admin should enter executable PHP code to be eval'd, why don't you let him enter the code directly and execute it the usual way. That way you'll also get the performance boost of any opcode cache installed.

Comment: because once the script is ready, kind off say an insert form, it will be accessed by the employees for daily records

Answer (score 0):

Generic answer: Use escaping functions when there is a change in context.

When putting a plain text string into SQL: Escape for SQL.

When putting a plain text string into HTML: Escape for HTML.

When putting a plain text string into an URL: Escape for URL.

When doing more than one thing of the above: Do all escaping in the right order, and really try to find out if you haven't missed a context change.

Demo question:

Start

```
$param = "foo";
$url = "http://www.example.org/newpage";
```

End

```
<a href="javascript:location='http://www.example.org/newpage?param=foo';return false;">Link</a>
```